# Google Cloud SDK error while deploying app: error 403 operation not allowed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Cloud SDK for publishing and trying to host my first basic site. Whenever I try to deploy app, it shows error 403: appengine.applications.get permission is required. I've tried each and every thing: searched a lot but still not able to find any solution. Also after changing project name and then browsing the site, it still shows error 404 ,requested url not found on the server.

link- udacitywork1.appspot.com

INDEX.HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, udacity!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello,Udacity!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

APP.YAML CODE

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

[image: error 404 screenshot]
[image: error 403 screenshot]

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I check the URL it's showing 'Hello,Udacity!' without any problem. I did not get any 404 error

Comment: yeah! but i updated the site to hello, udacity123! and then deployed then the error 403 came. then icahnged the project name to udacity1234. so the link becomes www.udacity1234.appspot.com. now u check the error 404 will show.

Comment: @nchhabra1311  Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: The app which works is someone's else's app (you wouldn't be the 1st one thinking to call it `udacitywork1`) - which is why you couldn't deploy.

Comment: The hostname in the url should become `<your_app_name>.appspot.com`, the leading `www.` is something else - you have nothing in the code justifying it.

Comment: @DanCornilescu the text couldn't be copied so i posted the image. Yeah you are right there is no www, thank u for correcting me. sorry but i think u didnt understood the problem! udacitywork1 got deployed the first time as it has a unique name so it is online  but on updating the app, it wasnt getting deployed . also considering your point i tried renaming it to udacity85415561 (random numbers) but still it wasnt getting deployed. it said permission required( error 403).. also as udacitywork1 was working, i changed its name and then browsed with new name, but it said page not found (error 404)

Comment: when deploying you need to deploy to *your* project - the name must match. Since you're not specifying the app's name during deployment and it's also not specified in the `app.yaml` file it means it's re-used from the `gcloud` config, possibly from a previous invocation. What does `gcloud app describe` says?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Previously , i added application: udacitywork1 in app.yaml but it said  " the [application] field is specified in <path>\app.yaml. This field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. project name should be either set by gcloud config set project <project_name> or by using --project flag"                      also 'gcloud app describe' gives the same error 403 as in the screenshot attached in description

Comment: Try resetting the project to the one you own: `gcloud init`, then `gcloud config set project <project_name>`. BTW, <project_name> is really the project ID, not literally its name. Only after getting valid info for *your* app from `gcloud app describe` there's no point trying something else.

Comment: @DanCornilescu using gcloud init shows options to select the project currently made using google cloud platform not by google cloud sdk (that are made locally, even their names are not being shown).  so as i understood what u said, i created a app on google cloud platform. then using gcloud init , set that as my current project. then renamed it to udacitywork1. then i browsed it so it was opening udacitywork1.appspot.com (the original link.). Then i did gcloud app describe but again the error 403.

Comment: @DanCornilescu  sir, can you please tell me a time at which you are free to help so that i could do whatever you would say side by side as it is taking too long to solve the problem and I AM REALLY EAGER TO LEARN THIS. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Over the weekend I can't tell an exact time except for probably 1-2h now and same tomorrow around the same time. More predictable during weekdays: Monday and Tuesday for example I can do ~9am to 3pm EST.

Comment: The projects made only locally don't matter - the cloud doesn't know about them and thus you can't do deployments for them. You can only deploy for projects that you see in the developer console.

Comment: And you can't `rename` a project once created. Use the name you see in displayed in the console.

Comment: @DanCornilescu No sir the deployments can be done for local projects , thats why they get hosted on the server just as this udacitywork1 got hosted. i have made it locally on my system and it got deployed the first time. but then the problem arised. n sir please correct me if i am wrong. i created a new project on google cloud platform . then using gcloud init , i set it up as my current project and then using gcloud config set project project_name, i changed its name and it showed success!

Comment: From terminology prospective the local execution is NOT considered deployment. Deployment is when the app is uploaded for execution on the GAE infra. If you had a different understanding you may need to edit your question accordingly. My comments are all with this understanding in mind.

Comment: no sir , you are right but i just wanted to tell that i am not EXECUTING it LOCALLY, i just have developed it locally ie the code written above is saved on my system but it is hosted on web. please the the [link] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website . I had just tried doing this

Comment: @DanCornilescu sir please reply!

Comment: I'm here right now...

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean when you say 'renamed' a project.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. So now you have a particular GAE project you want to work on, visible in the developer's Console. You need that project's ID set as current project in `gcloud` and you should be able to see its info in `gcloud app describe`. Can you do that?

Comment: I don't know how to start a chat manually...

Comment: @DanCornilescu by renaming I meant, i used gcloud config set project PROJECT_NAME  to a new name. yes I now have 2 different project... 1 in which is been shown in developer's console that i just created for checking and another on my system which i wanted to use. ans sir infact if You can check the above mentioned link, you will get to know precisely what i was doing... maybe it would help in making situation clear and issue may be resolved pretty fast...  and gcloud app descibe gave the error 403 for the project which I was using... the one saved locally

Comment: You can't `gcloud config set project PROJECT_NAME` to a project that doesn't exist in your dev console - that's why you get the 403. Create the project in the console and **then** use `gcloud config set project` for it.

Comment: That's the 'Before you begin' step #1 in the above mentioned link...

Comment: Are you still having the issue as I've noticed that Dan has pointed out the cause of the issue you were experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the project name locally to a project which doesn't exist on GAE is not gonna work - you'll get the 403 errors. The project **must** be visible in **your** developer console before you can reference it in the `gcloud` commands.

From the [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#before-you-begin) section in the [Quickstart for Python App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart):

> Before running and deploying this quickstart, you must set up a Cloud
>   Platform project for App Engine and then install the Cloud SDK:
>
> 1. Create a new Cloud Platform project and App Engine application using the Cloud Platform Console:
>
>    [Go to App Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/appengine/create?lang=python&st=true)
>
>    When prompted, select the [region](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#before-you-begin) where you want your App Engine application located. After your App Engine application is
>      created, the **Dashboard** opens.